# .NET Core Razor Routing to REST style routes

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am building an ASP.CORE Razor application and have the following directory structure:

```
Pages/Movies
Pages/Movies/Actors
```

There is an index page in each of the directories to show a list of movies and actors for a specific movie respectively.

I'm trying to build a link from each movie from the movies index page down to the actors index for a specific movie which always requires a movie ID.

The URL to find all actors for a movie should be

```
/Movies/{movieId}/Actors
```

Link from Movies index is

```
<a asp-page="./@movieModel.Id/Actors/Index">Actors</a>
```

@Page directive on the Actors index page is

```
@page "Movies/{movieId}/Actors/Index"
```

This does not work however because the link displayed on every movie is just `/movies` because I obviously don't have this wired up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have absolute url like `/Movies/1/Actors/Index` for Actor Index you need to use "/" at first

```
@page "/Movies/{movieId}/Actors/Index"
```

otherwise you would get url nested like `/Movies/Actors/Movies/1/Actors/Index`.

Besides `asp-page`, you could also use `@Url.Page`

```
<a href="@Url.Page("./Actors/Index",new { movieId = @movieModel.Id})">Actors</a>
<a asp-page="./Actors/Index" asp-route-movieId="@movieModel.Id">Actors</a>
```